# Delphi - How to save multiple Rave reports to one pdf file?

Tags: delphi, pdf, rave-reports

I have multiple rave reports(projects) in the project(the delphi project) and I want to save them all in one pdf file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have any real experience with Rave reports, I also had to perform stitching of multiple "pdf" pages to a single pdf document.  I ended up using [Gnostice PDFToolkit](http://www.gnostice.com/PDFtoolkit_VCL.asp) to do the final merge and it works quite well.  In my case I was generating multi-thousand page documents, so i'm sure it will fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Does Rave already export to PDF?  If so then there are a number of libraries that support merging of PDFs programmatically.  The main difference between them will be how many files they can merge at once (some support only two and some support merging a full array at once) and how quickly the output is produced.

If Rave doesn't already export to PDF, however, then you'd likely need a printer driver based PDF component.  The idea would be to tell Rave to print the report to a named virtual printer, then use the printer driver based component to capture that print job as a PDF.  Once you've got the PDF, you can do the merge.

It's been years since I've personally worked with Rave (last time was in the C++Builder/Delphi 6 days) but hopefully this helps.  If you need more info just let me know, I worked at Borland for a long time (before they became Embarcadero) and now work with PDF toolkits for developers.